# Symfony 3 - Open profiler generated by test environment (functional tests) in the browser

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, environment, profiler, functional-testing

I am trying to access to a profiler generated by a functional test with the method

```
$client->enableProfiler()
```

and by recovering the token with

```
$client->getProfile()->getToken()
```

but when I go to the page "/_profiler/{TOKEN}" I get the message

> Token not found
>   Token "{TOKEN}" was not found in the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the profiler is generated, it is placed in a cache folder corresponding to the current environment. The environment of the functional test is "test" and that of the browser is "dev".

To overcome the problem, it is possible to place the profilers generated by the test environment in the "/var/cache/dev" folder by adding in the configuration of the test environment (config_test.yml):

```
framework:
    profiler:
        dsn: 'file:%kernel.root_dir%/../var/cache/dev/profiler'
```

Comment: for symfony 5 it is 'file:%kernel.project_dir%/var/cache/dev/profiler'

Answer (score 2):

Profile tokens are environment related. 
Are you view the `/_profiler/{token}` url using the correct environment?

You could try temporarily setting env in .env to `TEST`

Comment: No, I used the environment "dev". This was indeed the problem as stated in the solution I proposed.  Your solution also works, however it involves changing the configuration file every time you go from dev to unit testing and vice versa.